# Get the name of the page in the content place holder of the Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

My `Master page` consists of a top bar that contains a few buttons and also a left menu bar by which the user can navigate through the web application. My `Login.aspx` page however is a content page but i do not want to show the left menu bar when the content page is login.

Here's a part of my Master page:

```
<div id="body">
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2" style="vertical-align: top">
                <div id="leftmenu">
                    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" StaticDisplayLevels="2" Font-Size="Medium">
                        <LevelSubMenuStyles>
                            <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="level1" />
                        </LevelSubMenuStyles>
                        <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="hoverstyle" />
                    </asp:Menu>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        &nbsp;
    </section>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to check for the name of the opened page in my `MainContent` of the Master Page file and if that page is `Login.aspx` I would set `Menu1` to hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think it in the opposite way: access a Master Page's control from Content Page.

This directive causes the content page's Master property to be strongly typed. Add this in you Content Page:

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/YourMasterPage.master" %>
```

Create the following Property inside your Master Page:

```
public bool IsMenuVisible
{
    get
    {
        return Menu1.Visible;
    }
    set
    {
        Menu1.Visible = value;
    }
}
```

Use it inside your Content Page:

```
Master.IsMenuVisible = false;
```

More information:

[Reference ASP.NET Master Page Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: Don't we have to cast the `Master` object to access our `Property`? `(Master as YourMasterPage).IsMenuVisible = false`;